# Can't get mysql_insert_id working, can't find the answer anywhere

Tags: mysql, sql

here's some php code that I'm trying to get working

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect(//);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO customers (fname, lname, address, suburb, postcode)
VALUES
('$_POST[firstname]','$_POST[lastname]','$_POST[address]','$_POST[suburb]','$_POST[postcode]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO orders (date, location, rego, bike_id)
VALUES
('$_POST[date]','$_POST[location]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[bid]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

My problem is, I can't get mysql_insert_id working. As it is, the echo doesn't display anything. If I try to put it in an insert, it comes up with 0. I'm a complete newbie (first time ever using php), so I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong. Any help massively appreciated.

Here are my tables:
Customers:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| cust_id  | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| fname    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| lname    | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| address  | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| suburb   | varchar(20) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| postcode | int(4)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Orders:

```
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| order_id | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| date     | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| location | varchar(65) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| rego     | varchar(65) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| cust_id  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| bike_id  | int(11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+----------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

The reason I am trying to do this is because when a user clicks submit on the order form, some details go to each table. I want the cust_id foreign key in orders to match the primary key of customers

Comment: Could you please post the Schema you are using? The problem might be there and not on the code level. You might have not set the ID field to auto_increment.

Comment: Just a guess here - is it legitimate to mix `mysqli` and `mysql` calls like this?

Comment: Try using http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try these two things:

1. mysqli::$insert_id instead of mysql_insert_id() because you are using mysqli_query()
   Ref# http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php
2. Use else case too because if insertion is not successful so you should not see the string "echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();"

Comment: I tried that, and it didn't seem to work. I really have no idea what is going on

Comment: are you getting any error? if yes, post here and do one thing, put "echo" before your $sql="INSERT INTO orders (date, location, rego, bike_id)
VALUES
('$_POST[date]','$_POST[location]','$_POST[state]','$_POST[bid]')";

by this you will know that either your prepared query is correct or not?

Comment: OK so I tried it using this syntax:  
printf ("New Record has id %d.\n", $mysqli->insert_id);  
and it returned "New Record has id 0

Comment: Try to echo $sql, its not your query. Try to echo your $sql and paste here.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. Do you just mean put the line: echo $sql   ? Because that just brings up the sql statement with the inputted values

Comment: Exactly!
I am asking for it because $_POST related variables are bringing some values and how they are affecting the query, i want to check.

Comment: Sure, so it prints:  INSERT INTO customers (fname, lname, address, suburb, postcode) VALUES ('As','B','C','D','2500')  Those are the values I entered

Comment: That's fine
Now use:
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();

after 1st if condition

and kindly echo the second $sql as well. There are two queries, and you are having 

echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();

after only 2nd query. Do you see?